# Can INSERT from QUERY_STRING but cannot SELECT that same value from MySQL!

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, insert

As you can see, there's *probably* no reason why it shouldn't be working. I don't know what else I can do, any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

All I am trying to do, is view check if the value entered at the end of the url, matches one that is in the database (and **yes**, it IS in the database. :)
Thank you

---

**The code:**

```
<?php

$keyword = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],11); 
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == "link")
    {
        $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
        $link    = $_POST['link'];

        $connection =
               mysql_connect("my01..com","h","h") or die(mysql_error());

        if($connection)
        {
         mysql_select_db("mysql_17902_h", $connection);

         mysql_query(
                 "INSERT INTO mysql_17902_h.links (
                   link,
                   keyword) VALUES (
                    '".$link."',
                      '".$keyword."')") or die(mysql_error());

            $state = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(!empty($_POST))
        {
            print_r($keyword);
            $connection =
                   mysql_connect("my01.h.com","h","h") or die(mysql_error());


            if($connection)
            {


                mysql_select_db("mysql_17902_h") or die(mysql_error());
           $result = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE keyword = $keyword")
           or die(mysql_error());

           $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
               $outsy = $row['link'];

           }
           $state = true;
           }

    }
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to execute a SELECT? Is there an Error or anything else?

Comment: That's my problem - SELECT statement bring no errors, and as you can see, I am using **print_r()** to output the value (i have also tried echo), but nothing gets outputted. So I have no way to tell if it is even SELECTin anything from the database in the first place.

Comment: This just for the sake of saying this. Escape your $_POST-data before inserting into database: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: Try adding apostrophes around you $keyword: keyword = '" . $keyword . "'

Comment: try putting quotes around '$keyword' in your select statement.

Comment: I was expecting someone to say that. I don't use security before I go live. - but thank you :)

Comment: le dorfier - I did that originally, but I took them away to see if it would work.

Comment: what did the statement look like with the quotes?

Comment: **"'.$example.'"** and **'".$example."'** - Neither of them worked, and neither of them dislpayed any errors.

Comment: I think I should post the whole page including HTML? Would that help?

Comment: Problem solved - but I don't know how because I can't remember what I just did to fix it :S   -   Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: in the future, try echo mysql_error(); after the query to see any errors.

Comment: BTW: your code is vulnerable to injection!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting your code so it's more legible:

```
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

$sql = <<<EOL;
INSERT INTO mysql_17902_h.links (link, keyword)
VALUES ('$link', '$keyword')
EOL;

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection attacks, and surrounding the variables with single quotes within the SQL string. You've neglected to do so here:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE keyword = $keyword") or ...
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

No quotes around a text-type field is a syntax error. As well, at that point in the code, $keyword contains whatever the `substr()` call at the top of the script returned, so make sure that substr call actually does what you're intending.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) I don't usually include anti-attack/security stuff until i've finished everything. And the quotes, I did originally have them, but was running out of ideas wheh trying to get this thing to work, so I removed them in a desperate attempt to hopefyully make it magically work. :P

Comment: It'd be better to include anti-attack stuff from the get-go. Far easier to do it then, since it's just one or two lines of code, usually, than have to remember everywhere it's necessary later - you'd likely miss a spot or two.